# Set Field in Column to 0 Based on Two Column Values Being Equal Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df using pandas with a list of permits and then a list of subpermits. I need to compare the Parent and Sub Permit columns, and if the Parent Permit is equal to the sub permit, set the Value total field to 0. The BLD-00045 row needs to retain the 70000 value essentially, but the ELE and PM need to be set to 0. Is this possible?

```
Parent Permit    Sub Permit    Value Total
BLD-00045         NaN          70000
ELE-2019         BLD-00045     100
PLM-2019         BLD-00045     200
```

My desired output would be this

```
Parent Permit    Sub Permit    Value Total
BLD-00045        NaN           70000
ELE-2019        BLD-00045      0
PLM-2019        BLD-00045      0
```

Comment: Can you also show the desired output, specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines of your data, I am guessing that in reality, there is some kind of hierarchical, tree-like structure of permits, and you are interested in assigning costs to only certain levels.

Based on your example, it sounds like you want to identify rows where the Sub Permit is equal to *any* parent permit.

You may want to try something like this:

```
parent_permits = df['Parent Permit'].unique()
has_sub_permit = df['Sub Permit'].isin(parent_permits)
df.loc[has_sub_permit, 'Value Total'] = 0
```

Two efficiency notes:

- If you need to check this condition repeatedly, you might consider adding a "Has Parent" column to the data frame.
- If the permit types are categorical in nature, you might consider using pandas' [Categorical datatype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) for those columns.  Pandas will then store values using integers, which may speed up operations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function that checks each row's `x["Sub Permit"]` value against EVERYTHING in the `x["Parent Permit"]`. If the "Sub Permit" is anywhere in "Parent Permit" (I assume it doesn't matter where) then set the value to `0`, otherwise use the original value of the "Sub Permit"s row's  `x["Value Total"]`

You can apply this method to every row in the DataFrame using the `df.apply()` method. To do this as a single line, use the Python `lambda`.

```
import pandas as pd

print(df)
print("---------__")
# lambda x: <return some value> if <x is condition> else <return some other value> 
df["Value Total"] = df.apply(lambda x: # use df.apply() to apply a lambda where x will be each row in the df
                             0 # Return this if True
                             if x["Sub Permit"] in # If the value of is ine Series created by...
                             df["Parent Permit"].unique() # All the unique values of df["Parent Permit"] 
                             else x["Value Total"], # otherwise return the original value found in else x["Value Total"] 
                             axis=1 #Use axis=1 (rows) and not axis=0 (columns
                             )
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Parent Permit Sub Permit  Value Total
0     BLD-00045        NaN        70000
1      ELE-2019  BLD-00045          100
2      PLM-2019  BLD-00046          200
---------__
Parent Permit Sub Permit  Value Total
0     BLD-00045        NaN        70000
1      ELE-2019  BLD-00045            0
2      PLM-2019  BLD-00046          200
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it.

```
list_of_parent_permits = x['Parent Permit'].tolist()
df['Value Total'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['Sub Permit'] in list_of_parent_permits else x['Value Total'], axis = 1)
```